# ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound in Users#show - debugging in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, activerecord

I have single table inheritance set up like follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.types
    %w(Status Image)
  end
end

class Image < Post
///
end

class Status < Post
///
end
```

A Post has a type Image or type Status

Here is my (simplified) users controller - show action and corresponding view:

```
 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @posts = @user.posts.order(created_at: :desc)
 end


<%@posts.each do |x|%>    (<- error : line 31) 
<%=x.body%>
<%end%>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Showing /app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #31 raised:


The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'status'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Post.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.
```

Note: I KNOW this error is happening due to some bad post entry for only this particular user, i just don't know how to debug this - and find out exactly which post entry is causing my error. I also know if i reset my database , the error should go away, but i really want to figure this out the right way. (This error does not happen if i go to a different user show page, so I know it is a post connected to this user).

Any help please?

Note: Ive tried the following (but still get the same error):

```
  <%#=debug @posts%>
  <%#=@posts.inspect%>
  <%#=simple_format @posts.to_yaml%>
```

I know there is perhaps a flaw in the way I am viewing this issue, but I would really appreciate a step/push in the right direction.

To re-iterate, I am looking for a good way to debug issues like this (Ive run into this problem in the past) where the data that has been entered causes the code to break

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've stored the `type` field for a `Post` as `status` and not `Status`. Note the capital S. It's hard to tell without seeing the data itself.

Comment: Yea I'm sure that's what I've done too, but is there anyway I can see this data ?

Comment: Open up the `rails console` and do `Post.all`. It should show you.